# Its returning undefined, why does it not return the db query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

When I console.log result it gives me the result, but then when I console.log outside the function, its undefined. Both Console.log return undefined. Using Javascript and Node.js (mongoDB database).

```
function getAllScores() {
  var scoresFromDb = db.account.find({}, { username: 1, score: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return result;
  })
  return scoresFromDb;
}

var allScores = getAllScores();

console.log(allScores + ' all'); 

console.log(getAllScores());
```

Comment: have a look into async functions...

Comment: This is known as Out-of-Sync mistake. db.acount.find is an async function so thw two console.log run before getAllScores's finished

Comment: Seen Ajax examples but still not sure how to fix this code unfortunatly